# python3.6 create win32 shortcut with unicode

Tags: python, python-3.6, pywin32, win32com

I have this `python3.6` code that creates Windows shortcuts:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
path_to_target = r"C:\Program Files\ピチャーム\pycharm64.exe"
path_to_shortcut = r"C:\Program Files\pycharm.lnk"
shell = Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path_to_shortcut)             
shortcut.Targetpath = path_to_target  # exception here
shortcut.save()
```

If `path_to_target` contains any non ascii characters I get an exception: `Property '&lt;unknown&gt;.Targetpath' can not be set.`

The code works OK and creates the proper shortcut if `path_to_target` is only ascii characters.

How can I create shortcuts to targets that have unicode characters?

Is there alternative API to create Windows shortcuts?

Comment: Maybe this is some help for you. https://superuser.com/questions/1129549/ascii-in-powershell-wscript-shell/1140538#1140538

Comment: @mbieren, that has to do with name of the link and not the target of the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pythoncom` instead which is Unicode compatible. Also not the target directory for the shortcut must exist before hand.

Tested with python 3.6 64-bit

```
import os
import pythoncom
from win32com.shell import shell

shortcut_dir = r"C:\test\ピチャーム"
if not os.path.exists(shortcut_dir):
    os.makedirs(shortcut_dir)

path_to_shortcut = shortcut_dir + r"\_test.lnk"
path_to_target = r"C:\test\target.exe"

shortcut = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
    shell.CLSID_ShellLink, None, pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, shell.IID_IShellLink)
persist_file = shortcut.QueryInterface (pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile)
shortcut.SetPath(path_to_target)
persist_file.Save (path_to_shortcut, 0)
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it's the best answer, and it works! You can also add a working directory: `shortcut.SetWorkingDirectory(working_dir_path)`.

Comment: @PeriodicMaintenance, this is the same code as mine instead of using `comtypes` it uses another library `pythoncom`

Comment: @PeriodicMaintenance Tarun's answer is the exact same as Barmak. And since he posted first, I think its only fair to award the bounty to him.

Comment: @TarunLalwani, Tarun's code is NOT the same as Barmak - certainly not exact same. 1st, as Tarun's said, it uses a different library that needs to be pip installed separately. 2nd Barmak's code worked out of the box without need to fix.

Comment: @PeriodicMaintenance, no worries. You can choose whichever answer you find best and award that answer the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by making sure not to use shell but the direct `ShellLink` object

```py
import comtypes
import comtypes.shelllink
import comtypes.client
import comtypes.persist

shortcut = comtypes.client.CreateObject(comtypes.shelllink.ShellLink)
shortcut_w = shortcut.QueryInterface(comtypes.shelllink.IShellLinkW)
shortcut_file = shortcut.QueryInterface(comtypes.persist.IPersistFile)

shortcut_w.SetPath ("C:\\Temp\\हिंदी टायपिंग.txt")
shortcut_file.Save("C:\\Temp\\हिंदी.lnk", True)
```

[image: Created]

**Update 1**

Thanks to @Axois comments, I have verified that your original code works if you set the unicode support

[image: Unicode support]

PS: Comments in [this](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/163182-unicode-aware-file-shortcuts-windows) question pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Adding on to this answer, the reason why you are getting a unicode error can be fixed by going to `Region & language` -> `Administrative language settings` -> `Change system locale` -> check `Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`

Comment: Thanks @Axois, never even knew there is a setting like that on Windows

Comment: No worries, I was stumped initially at the beginning too, because I've got the same error as him (`Property '&lt;unknown&gt;.Targetpath' can not be set.`) and i solved it by applying that settings. However I got stuck when trying to create the shortcut in the `C:\ `. Creating shortcuts with that japanese text works fine in the desktop.

Comment: That may be because windows prevent programs creating stuff in `C:\ ` if they don't have admin access

Comment: I see, im going to post mine as the answer if you dont mind, because I have spent some time and effort researching around for answers too.

Comment: Sure, you should go ahead and post your findings

Comment: @TarunLalwani: this code looks promising, but does not work. the line `from comtypes.client import IShellLinkW` produces ImportError. Also `objShortCut` is not defined.

Comment: I will fix that, just refactored a bit before posting tested code

Comment: @PeriodicMaintenance, please check the updated code now, have run and tested it.